# How many Hashes are in a single Terrahash

Tags: hashpower

Im looking at getting an ASIC that runs about 1 Th/s and im wondering how many hashes is equal to a terrahash?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tera is an SI prefix that means *1 trillion*.

That means 1 terahash/s means 1,000,000,000,000 hashes per second.